# $in is not working in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have two documents with "Name" values "Raja_5" and "Raja_6".
I have written the following codes to update the city in two documents.

```
collection.update({"Name":{"$in":["Raja_5","Raja_6"]}},{"$set":{"City":"Hyd"}})
```

(or)

```
collection.update({"$or":[{"Name":"Raja_5"},{"Name":"Raja_6"}]},{"$set":{"City":"Hyd"}})
```

But the document with "Raja_5" is getting updated but not the other document  in both the cases.

Please help me.

Comment: Thank you Blakes Seven, Its working in shell but not from pymongo

Comment: `multi=True` is pymongo syntax

Comment: Thanks Blakes Seven, Could you please let me know if there is a document for learning Pymongo Syntax.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the 'multi' operator is not been set.

```
db.collection.update({"$or":[{"Name":"Raja_5"},{"Name":"Raja_6"}]},{"$set":{"City":"Hyd"}},  { multi: true })
```

above is the shell command for it.

for pymongo, i think it can be done as below

```
collection.update({"$or":[{"Name":"Raja_5"},{"Name":"Raja_6"}]},{"$set":{"City":"Hyd"}}, multi=True)
```

In version 3.0, `update_many` operation has been introduced with format as :

```
update_many(filter, update, upsert=False)
```

http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_many

Comment: Thanks Anish, This is working in shell but not from pymongo. Please let me know if you know the solution

Comment: yeah, i put the shell command there :) .I have edited it now

Comment: Anish, where can we get the syntax of Pymongo.

Comment: It would be like collection.update({}, {$set...}, multi=True) and you can use update({}, { "$set": ....}, upsert=False, multi=True) in cases when you want to use upsert as well. I have edited answer to put that.

Comment: Thanks Anish for your help, I mean to say, is there a book/document for Pymongo Synatx

Comment: Syntax :
http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html

Tutorial : 
http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html

Online course : 
https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M101P/about

Answer (score 1):

The following code is working now

```
collection.update({
    "Name": {
    "$in": ["Raja_5", "Raja_6"]
    }
  }, {
    "$set": {
    "City": "Hyd"
    }
  }, "false", "true")
```